# Customize Red Hat installation - /mnt/runtime directory

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, kickstart, anaconda

I am installing a RHEL 5.5. I have seen one DVD that have a complex %pre script in ks.cfg and it used some customized python scripts in /mnt/runtime. It's cool and I wish to customize installation like that. I believe /mnt/runtime and its files are provided by anaconda, but how to add customized files in it (or some other directories that exist during installation)?

I read about anaconda / kickstart manuals but don't find much information regarding this.

Please comment

Thanks! XM

Comment: Can you be more specific about the customization you want to perform? You probably DO want a kickstart file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure for custom install DVD:

1. Create a custom kickstart file. (You can install the OS on a system interactively, once, then harvest the anaconda-ks.cfg file from /root to get started. You can modify that file to suit your needs.
2. Copy the RHEL/CentOS install DVD to a working folder (we will call it `/tmp/dvdroot`), and don't forget the hidden `.treeinfo` and `.diskinfo` files.
3. Copy your customized kickstart file (we will assume it's called ks.cfg) to `/tmp/dvdroot`.
4. Edit `/tmp/dvdroot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`. There are several blocks of label/kernel/append. Duplicate one, and edit one to resemble this:

> label special
>
> kernel vmlinuz
>
> append ***ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg*** initrd=initrd.img

Run the following commands

`cd /tmp/dvdroot`

`mkisofs -quiet -r -T -J -V "Special Install Disk" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
 -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
 -boot-info-table -o ../special-dvd.iso .`

Do *not* forget that last dot on the previous command.

Now burn `/tmp/special-dvd.iso` to blank DVD media:

`cdrecord -dao /tmp/special-dvd.iso`

When you use the DVD to install a system and you get to the install prompt, enter `special`.

Comment: These instructions were tested with RHEL5.4. They should work with any Enterprise Linux version 5.x (i.e. Centos5.x or RHEL5.x) and will very likely work with any Fedora since Fedora 7.

Comment: I have **not** vetted these instructions, but at first glance, they look helpful: http://cinq.com/2008/04/14/rebuilding-the-dvd-iso-for-centos-5-or-rhel-5/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to provide the files via HTTP, either directly or via a yum repo.

Comment: By HTTP, do you mean to have it look for the files on LAN with specific URL?

Comment: Yes. HTTP as used by a browser, rpm, and yum.

Comment: Thanks for the sound solution. However I realized we don't have a stable resource (to provide the files), nor connection to them; the server will be running in a existing, stable telecom topology. Do you have a solution that comes with single DVD and include all custom files on it? My guess is I need to modify some anaconda resources.